# PubNub GCM for Unity Android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, pubnub

I have successfully integrated PubNub into my Unity project. The chat function is working. Now I am looking for a way to receive push notifications when the user is offline.

I am familiar with how GCM works. So basically, I can find the GCM API key and put it in PubNub dashboard. However, on Unity side, I suppose there has to be a plugin for this but I cannot find it anywhere.

Comment: HI Chatpong thank you for the question if you connect with us on support@pubnub.com we can chat further.

Comment: @PubNub thanks for your reply. I have sent an email to support :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To send the GCM push notifications to the device:

- You need use our REST API to register the device (http://www.pubnub.com/docs/unity3d-c-sharp/mobile-gateway#gcm_prerequisites) and
- then publish the message in this format: http://www.pubnub.com/docs/unity3d-c-sharp/mobile-gateway#sending_a_gcm_test_message_via_pubnub

To process GCM notifications using unity you need a third party asset like the ones here (Currently our Unity SDK doesn’t have the feature):

- [How to receive a message when the app is in background? (Android, Unity, GCM)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24939272/how-to-receive-a-message-when-the-app-is-in-background-android-unity-gcm)
- http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/released-utnotifications-professional-cross-platform-push-notifications-and-more.333045/
- https://github.com/kobakei/unity-gcm
- http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/google-cloud-messaging-for-android-using-unity.177747/

Or develop a “service” that will keep running in the background, using Java, to process the notification and pass to the Unity app. You need a service outside Unity because Unity apps are killed when they in background (runInBackground is unreliable on mobile devices).

- http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/application-runinbackground-is-not-working-on-android.117723/
- [Checking if an Android application is running in the background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3667022/checking-if-an-android-application-is-running-in-the-background)

Comment: Sorry, I am quite new to Stackoverflow. Now I have accepted :)